# Updating multiple html files with gulp-usemin

Tags: javascript, gulp, browserify

I'm using gulp-usemin and it seems to work fine when only updating a single html file, but when I try to make it update multiple html files, it crashes.  This is my usemin task now.  Notice that I've duplicated the code, once for the login.html file and again for the index.html file.  What I'd like to do is just pass in an arry like `gulp.src([_appdir + '/login.html', _appdir + '/index.html'], {base: _appdir})` but that's what seems to make my task bomb.  Even tried using `*.html` instead and I get the same problem.

```
gulp.task('usemin', ['browserify', 'sass'], function() {
  gulp.src([_appdir + '/images/**/*'], {base: _appdir})
    .pipe(gulp.dest(_publicdir));

  gulp.src([_appdir + '/login.html'], {base: _appdir})
    .pipe(usemin({
      css: [minifyCss({keepSpecialComments: 0}), 'concat', rev()],
      html: [gulpif(argv.production, minifyHtml({conditionals: true, quotes: true}))],
      jsOldIE: [uglify(), rev()],
      jsVendor: [uglify(), rev()],
      jsBundle: [
        gulpif(argv.production, rev()),
        gulpif(argv.production, uglify()),
        gulpif(argv.production, rename({suffix: '.min'}))
      ]
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(_publicdir));

  return gulp.src([_appdir + '/index.html'], {base: _appdir})
    .pipe(usemin({
      css: [minifyCss({keepSpecialComments: 0}), 'concat', rev()],
      html: [gulpif(argv.production, minifyHtml({conditionals: true, quotes: true}))],
      jsOldIE: [uglify(), rev()],
      jsVendor: [uglify(), rev()],
      jsBundle: [
        gulpif(argv.production, rev()),
        gulpif(argv.production, uglify()),
        gulpif(argv.production, rename({suffix: '.min'}))
      ]
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(_publicdir));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`gulp-usemin` currently has a bug which prevents you from using multiple `<!-- build:name ... -->` comments with the same name. If there are two `<!-- build:css ... -->` sections in the same file this will also trigger the bug.

I wound up using `useref` instead, and I didn't even have to change my HTML.

Comment: After about an hour of trying to define multiple blocks I found your answer. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

This question is old but the problem is common, and many people on the net are searching for solution, and there is no clear solution in top google results. I'm new to gulp and webdev, so sorry for any inconvenience.

For simple functions without parameters you can just remove parenthesis:

```
jsOldIE: [uglify, rev],
```

If you need parameters, then create anonymous function

```
css: [
    function() { return minifyCss({keepSpecialComments: 0}); }, 
    'concat', rev],
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use gulp-foreach

```
gulp.task('usemin', ['browserify', 'sass'], function() {
  gulp.src([_appdir + '/images/**/*'], {base: _appdir})
    .pipe(gulp.dest(_publicdir));

  return gulp.src([_appdir + '/login.html', _appdir + '/index.html'], {base: _appdir})
    .pipe(foreach(function (stream, file) {

      return stream.pipe(usemin({
        css: [minifyCss({keepSpecialComments: 0}), 'concat', rev()],
        html: [gulpif(argv.production, minifyHtml({conditionals: true, quotes: true}))],
        jsOldIE: [uglify(), rev()],
        jsVendor: [uglify(), rev()],
        jsBundle: [
          gulpif(argv.production, rev()),
          gulpif(argv.production, uglify()),
          gulpif(argv.production, rename({suffix: '.min'}))
        ]
      }))
      .pipe(gulp.dest(_publicdir));
    }))
})
```